# using fdb on mac os opens in opera and not firefox

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, fdb

Is there a way to set the flex debugger (fdb) to automatically open the debuggable swf in firefox instead of Opera?

The app I am starting from works in firefox but not Opera and it does not have to support Opera anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the primary browser for Eclipse.  Should be under Options->General->Web Browsers.  Select the 'use external browser' radiobutton and select the browser you want to use (or add it if it's not there).